# Detect Phone number in a NSString

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

I want to extract the phone number from a NSString.

For ex: In the string **Call John @ 994-456-9966**, i want to extract **994-456-9966**.

I have tried code like,

```
NSString *nameRegex =@"(\(\d{3}\)\s?)?\d{3}[-\s\.]\d{4}"; 
NSPredicate *nameTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY keywords.name CONTAINS[c] %@",nameRegex]; 
validationResult=[nameTest evaluateWithObject:phoneNo];
```

but i couldnt get exact result. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, try these http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number

Comment: @sri priya: thanks for ur help. But im not looking for regular expression.

Comment: The code you are showing is for creating a predicate to filter results from a Core Data or memory data base. Why are you doing this? Do you want to extract all the contact from you database that have a phone number associated that way?

Comment: @marzapower i just want to extract from a nSString. Can u redefine my predicate??

Comment: I answer directly to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, I think:

```
NSString *myString = @"John @ 123-456-7890";
NSString *myRegex = @"\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}";
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:myRegex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];

NSString *phoneNumber = nil;
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    phoneNumber = [myString substringWithRange:range];
    NSLog(@"%@", phoneNumber);
} else {
    NSLog(@"No phone number found");
}
```

You can rely on the default Regular Expression search mechanism built into Cocoa. This way you will be able to extract the range corresponding to the phone number, if present.

Remember do alway double-escape backslashes when creating regular expressions.

Adapt your regex accordingly to the part of the phone number you'd like to extract.

#### Edit

Cocoa provides really simple tools for handling regular expressions. For more complex needs, you should look at the powerful [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/) extension for Cocoa projects.

Comment: Can we detect multiple phone numbers in a same string?

Comment: I think you can accomplish this task with a sort of two-stage search. I mean, you isolate the phone numbers with a regex, then split them if you now how they are separated. For more complex needs you can refer to the `RegexKitLite` extension as stated in the updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the official NSDataDetector in iOS 4.0

```
phoneLinkDetector = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:
          (NSTextCheckingTypeLink | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber) error:nil];


NSUInteger numberOfPhoneLink = [[self phoneLinkDetector] numberOfMatchesInString:tweet
                          options:0  range:NSMakeRange(0, tweet.length)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString * number = @"(555) 555-555 Office";
NSString * strippedNumber = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [number length])];
```

> Result: 555555555

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are having "@" symbol in all phone numbers.

```
NSString *list = @"Call John @ 994-456-9966";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"]
```

or

You can use the [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to extract the phone number.

EDIT:After seeing the comments.
Assume that you are having only 12 characters in your mobile numbers.

```
length=get the total length of the string.
index=length-12;

NSString *str=[myString substringFromIndex:index];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help. Bt not all string has @

Answer (score 0):

if u need just the number u can filter out the special characters and use nsscanner

```
NSString *numberString = @"Call John @ 994-456-9966";
NSString *filteredString=[numberString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:filteredString];
[aScanner scanInteger:anInteger];
```